# How to check if new Outlook calendar event has been added?

Tags: php, laravel-4, office365api, outlook-calendar

Say I have a 'Sync Calendar' button that when clicked goes and grabs the maximum number of events (50) from Outlook API.  The next time it's clicked it uses the pagination link to get the next 50 events and so on.  Now say that a user logs into their Outlook calendar and adds a new event in the date range of the first 50 events that I have already fetched.  What's a good strategy/logic for checking for a new event in a date range that's already been fetched?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Sync events API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Syncevents) to synchronize events in an Outlook calendar view , below is the basic steps of the sync events scenario:

1.use the initial sync request to get the get new, modified, or deleted events     within a specific time range from a user's calendar:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/{user_context}/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

2.consider that a user add an event to calendar .

3.Use the deltaToken or skipToken value from the previous request to issue the next request:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/{user_context}/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}&$deltatoken={delta_token}
```

4.In the response you will find the information of the new event , if the response body also includes an @odata.deltaLink with a deltaToken value, indicating that sync is complete for that calendar view.

For more details ,please click [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view) .